# c# How to look for specific pattern in a string?

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

I have a string containing letters and numbers. This string also contains a Date that I want to extract.

example : `anv749dld95hd01/01/2012ncjf739dkcju`

I want to get new string that will contain : `01/01/2012`

The only thing I thought is to split it using :`str.Split('/')`
this way I will get an array and work on each cell  - take the two last characters of the first cell, get the value of the second cel and then get the first 4 characters from the third cell.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you can use Regex

Comment: 1) Can this string contain any unicode characters? 2) Is the format always `dd/mm/yyyy` or should it depend on the locale?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you could potentially use a regular expression:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Test
{    
    static void Main()
    {
        var input = "anv749dld95hd01/01/2012ncjf739dkcju";
        var regex = new Regex(@"\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}");
        var match = regex.Match(input);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Got match: {0}", match.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No match found");
        }
    }
}
```

(You could call `Match.NextMatch` to check that there's only *one* match.)

To parse this as a `DateTime`, you'd then use something like this:

```
string dateText = match.Value;
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateText, "dd/MM/yyyy",
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                           DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
{
    // Use date
}
else
{
    // Couldn't parse the value
}
```

(We can't tell whether it's meant to be `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`; adjust as required.)

You could also additionally tighten up the regex if you wanted, such that the first digit of the month has to be 0 or 1, and the first digit of the day has to be 0, 1 or 2. It depends on what your data is like, really.

Comment: based on example \d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: Doh, yes, fixed.

Comment: Worth pointing out that this is for things that *look* like dates, the OP should TryParseExact the matches to check.

Comment: @AlexK.: Sure, will do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can find the first forward slash and start substring two characters before and take ten characters.

```
string date = str.Substring(s.IndexOf('/')-2, 10);
```

You can Parse the substring using [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have to ensure if you got the right substring.

```
bool isParsed = DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "dd/MM/YYYY", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out x1);
```

Comment: what if string doesn't contain pattern?

Comment: Pattern is even required for regex isn't it?

Comment: you can check if match exists and pattern success by match.Success

Comment: But a regex wont fail whereas `substring(-3, ..` will throw

Comment: It will fail if date does not exists and given substring could be parsed to validate

Answer (score 0):

Use RegEx to find the pattern and return the desired string.